# XAML - setting textbox contents to zero when user deletes contents

Tags: c#, xaml

Being new to XAML I wonder if anyone can tell me how to do the following:

I have a textbox pre-populated with a decimal. Users can manually set this to zero, but if they delete the contents of the textbox it retains the original value as the decimal cannot be null.
If the user decides to delete rather than type "0", how can I convert that to 0?
Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Are you using MVVM?
But more important: which value do you expect when the user deletes the value?

Comment: Yes, MVVM. If the if the user deletes the value, I want to show "0" as the new value.  Currently they hit delete and the textbox looks to be null, if they then save, the original value is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `TextChanged` event on your textbox.

i.e:
Xaml file:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" TextChanged="myTextBox_TextChanged" ... />
```

Code behind:

```
 private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
     var control = sender as TextBox;
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(control.Text))
     {
          control.Text = "0";
     }
 }
```

Hope it helps!