# Validating a deleted decimal value on a form which shows as null/empty

Tags: c#, xaml

I previously asked this question 
[XAML - setting textbox contents to zero when user deletes contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756458/xaml-setting-textbox-contents-to-zero-when-user-deletes-contents/43756813#43756813][1]) to which I received a workable solution.

I have now been asked to change the way this is being done.  Rather than set the text to "0" when the user deletes the textbox contents, it must be a required field.

So if a user deletes the text contents rather than type "0", I need to catch that as being null to force some validation.
The problem is that on deletion the original value is held in the model as it's a decimal and can't be set to null, if I do as the answer to my previous question suggests, then I set it to 0 on delete, either way I can't seem to force validation.

I'm thinking, is there a way to check if the text is empty from the viewmodel? I realize this has to be separate from the view so technically you shouldn't look at this approach, but I'm just trying to set out what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation for that needs to be done in the view. [Validation rules are the natural choice for how to do it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx). The viewmodel can't and shouldn't even know the view exists, much less have any references to controls. That would be painful to implement, and even more painful to live with.

```
public class RequiredDecimalRule : ValidationRule
{
    public RequiredDecimalRule()
    {
    }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        decimal d;

        if (value == null || !Decimal.TryParse(value.ToString(), out d))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Numeric value is required");
        }

        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBox
    >
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding
            Path="SomeDecimalPropertyOnYourViewModel">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:RequiredDecimalRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

If you're not allowed to touch the view, then you shouldn't be responsible for this validation. But sometimes that can happen. What you do then is have two properties: One decimal and one string. The string one is bound to the textbox in the view. The actual decimal one isn't bound to the view. When either property gets a new value, it updates the other one. In the case where the string one gets a null or an empty string, do your error thing instead of updating the decimal property.